# Can I use Sublime to edit CSS files within a Visual Studio 2010 project

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, tfs, sublimetext2

Is there a way to automatically launch Sublime from within Visual Studio 2010, for example, every time I click open a CSS file? I need all the source control functionality to remain intact - I just want to change which editor gets used for a few filetypes within VS / TFS projects. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the file, select "open with...", add sublime as an editor, click set default.

You'll probably need to right click checkout/checkin manually in visual studio still.  This functionality is a lot nicer in tfs2012/vs2012 when using local workspaces as files are no longer marked as readonly.